# Can we make requests to the Bing Search API faster than the standard 1 query/sec?

Tags: search, limit, bing-api

We are using a free account of **Bing Search API** for evaluation and we found it getting us proper results in a very reasonable time. We are planning to extend our account by purchasing a subscription package. We want to ask some questions regarding (QPS) **Query Per Second limit**:

- Can we have it increased?
- Are there any packages that we need to purchase that have certain
  increased limit?

Comment: Did you try making the request from a browser? see its original speed

Comment: @Newbee Dev - we are using curl.

Comment: The curl might makes it slower but the actual api speed might fast

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any of the paid tiers allow for higher throughput:

[image: BingSearchAPI query rates from Cognitive Services on Azure --- S1: 10/s; S2: 50/s; S3: 100/s; S4: 125/s; S5: 150/s]

If you need instructions on how to signup for a paid bing subscription, I've posted a guide in an answer to this question: [Unable to find Subscription Key for Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757076/unable-to-find-subscription-key-for-microsoft-cognitive-services/40772586?noredirect=1#comment68820834_40772586)